# Why can't gdb see assembly source files

Tags: assembly, gdb

When you debug C/C++ code in gdb, you can for example use list command to see source file you are debugging. But if you introduce assembly function(s) and try to list source, gdb does not see it. "Info sources" also sees only C files.

I know I can disassemble the code, but I'd like to see source with comments and so on.
I have checked the object file corresponding to assembly source and the name of source file isn't even recorded there (it is for C files).

Is this behavior by design? Am I missing some flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as compilers require a flag to have debugging info produced, so do assemblers.  Not knowing what assembler you are using, I couldn't say just what flag(s) you'd need.

Comment: I'm using gcc (which executes gnu assembler). I'm using -g3 flag.

Comment: gcc has a -Wa flag for passing options to the assembler; looks like the assembler also uses -g to signal generation of debugging info.

Comment: Thanks. On x86 gcc it actually works also by only passing -g to gcc (which passes it to as). I was actually playing around with other toolchain where it does not, but mistakenly came to conclusion that this is generic GNU as behavior.